# Asp.net Membership Provider shows login information in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm not sure what I did, but now my site is showing this as the url:

```
http://localhost:53187/Customer/AccountScreen?UserName=testx&Password=test12345&RememberMe=False&AccountId=5b89d595-ef19-4feb-b95d-bf39672c9ac4
```

I am calling the customer's account screen like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("AccountScreen", "Customer", model);
```

So, I don't see why it's now displaying this in the url now. That really seems like a bad practice to me.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why are you passing the model to the RedirectToAction method. The third parameter is for routeValues.

Whatever you pass to the routeValues parameter will expose its properties in the url. Just remove the third parameter and it will be ok. If you need to pass anything to the AccountScreen use something like

```
return RedirectToAction("AccountScreen", "Customer", new { id = model.Id });
```

Comment: didn't need model, it was an older method that I hadn't updated so I removed the need and it works fine now. Ty for the explaination.

Answer (score 2):

You could include only the values you are interested in:

```
return RedirectToAction(
    "AccountScreen", 
    "Customer", 
    new { AccountId = mode.AccountId }
);
```

will redirect to `http://localhost:53187/Customer/AccountScreen?AccountId=5b89d595-ef19-4feb-b95d-bf39672c9ac4`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. I am not passing the login information and its not in the model, it is being handled by the Membership provider.

Comment: The membership provider doesn't do any redirects. What properties do you have in the `model` that you are passing to the RedirectToAction method? Sorry I might have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

[RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method returns an `HTTP 302` response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a `GET` request to the specified action. So, what you see is a get request with model as route values. HTTP doesn't support redirection using POST, so you can't change that.

What you can do - call method from your controller without returning to browser (if this is a same controller):

```
return AccountScreen(model);
```

---

You can use [TempData](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/23/37947/) to store your model (this also will be GET request, but model will not be passed in route values - it will be stored in session). In your controller:

```
TempData["model"] = model;
return RedirectToAction("AccountScreen", "Customer");
```

In Customer controller:

```
public ActionResult AccountScreen()
{
    YourModel model = TempData["model"] as YourModel;
    //...
}
```

Comment: it's not within the same controller :(

Comment: Well first solution that comes to my mind is instantiating Customer controller and calling its AccountScreen method. Thats brute, but should work.